# crosscompile can't find header files for net-snmp (i686/mips64)

Tags: gcc, header, cross-compiling, net-snmp, mips64

I'm currently trying to cross compile onto mips64 using a shared object library, when I run the following command:

```
toby@cbmFinal:~/x-tools/mips64-n64-linux-gnu/bin$ ./mips64-n64-linux-gnu-gcc -I /home/toby/Downloads/net-snmp-5.5.2.1/include/net-snmp/ -L /usr/lib64/libnetsnmp.so ~/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c -o snmpdemoapp
```

It throws an error saying it can't find the header files:

```
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c:1:38: error: net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h: No such file or directory
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c:2:40: error: net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h: No such file or directory
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c: In function 'main':
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c:14: error: 'netsnmp_session' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c:14: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/toby/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c:14: error: expected ';' before 'session'
```

etc etc

I have checked the dir and they're all there, I can also do them each manually using -include but then have a bunch of other headers I can't all -include.

```
toby@cbmFinal:~/Downloads/net-snmp-5.5.2.1/include/net-snmp$ ls
agent             definitions.h  mib_api.h.gch         output_api.h   session_api.h.gch  utilities.h
config_api.h      library        net-snmp-config.h     pdu_api.h      snmpv3_api.h       varbind_api.h
config_api.h.gch  machine        net-snmp-config.h.in  pdu_api.h.gch  system             varbind_api.h.gch
data_access       mib_api.h      net-snmp-includes.h   session_api.h  types.h            version.h
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to remove space after `-I` and `-L` options, like shown [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)?

Comment: yep removed space, same problem

Comment: provide just this path `-I/home/toby/Downloads/net-snmp-5.5.2.1/include/`, i.e. without `net-snmp`.

Comment: ah! thank you that has fixed the missing header files issue, however the undeclared reference errors still remain. It's as if it is ignoring the library.

Comment: Have you looked at [Buildroot project](http://buildroot.uclibc.org)? It already provides net-snmp and many other libraries.

Comment: Was just syntax all along, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, was a syntax error.

Correct command was:

```
toby@cbmFinal:~/x-tools/mips64-n64-linux-gnu/bin$ ./mips64-n64-linux-gnu-gcc -I/home/toby/Downloads/net-snmp-5.5.2.1/include/ -L/usr/lib64 -lnetsnmp ~/BsDiagnostics/snmpdemoapp.c -o snmpdemoapp
```